# ¿Anclar columna al hacer scroll horizontal en wpf, XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

Como puedo hacer que la primera columna de un datagrid quedé anclada al hacer scroll horizontal,que siempre permanezca inmóvil, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para congelar la columna y que no se mueva al hacer scroll utiliza la propiedad FrozenColumnCount, se aplica así:

```
<DataGrid FrozenColumnCount ="1" />
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó!